# como convertir un String a un objeto json en delphi XE 4

Tags: json, postgresql, delphi

Tengo una función en mi base de datos de postgres que me devuelve un json :

```
DECLARE 
si_user integer:=0;
si_pass dclave:='';
BEGIN
select count(*), passwrd from usuarios where clave = usuario 
    group by passwrd 
    into si_user, si_pass;
if si_user > 0 then
    if si_pass = passwd then    
        UPDATE userstatus SET ipadress = ipaddr, acceso = now()
            WHERE clave = usuario;
        EXECUTE format('SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(u))) 
            FROM (SELECT * FROM usuarios 
            WHERE clave = ''%s'' AND passwrd = ''%s'' )
                u;', usuario, passwd)
            INTO result;
    else
        result ='[{"password":"erroneo"}]';
        end if;
else
    result ='[{"usuario":"erroneo"}]';
end if;
```

Que me devuelve...

```
[{"clave":"Jperez", "passwd"."juancho1804","nivel":"1","direccion":"Añil 45-B, Col. Santa Martha. CDMX 13100","celular":"552534.5898","extension":"308","email":"juan-perez@disind.com","ctagoogle":"juncho@gmail.com"}]
```

Y una función en DataSnap server, que recibe un parámetro de tipo string con los valores clave, passwd e Ip

```
function TServerMethods.Usuario(const datos: string): string;
var
   qry: TADQuery;
   clave, pass, ipaddr: string;
   p: integer;
   valores, respuesta: string;
begin
    qry := TADQuery.Create(nil);
    try
     // traigo la primera coma de la cadena...
    p := Ansipos(',', datos);
    clave := copy(datos, 1, (p - 1));
    valores := copy(datos, p + 1);
    p := Ansipos(',', valores);
    pass := copy(valores, 1, (p - 1));
    ipaddr := copy(valores, p + 1);
    try
      qry.Connection := ADConnection1;
      qry.SQL.Text := 'select * from login_user(:clave, :passwrd, :ipaddr)';
      qry.params.ParamByName('clave').Value := clave;
      qry.params.ParamByName('passwrd').Value := pass;
      qry.params.ParamByName('ipaddr').Value := ipaddr;
      qry.Active := True;
      if not qry.Eof then
        respuesta := qry.FieldByName('result').AsString;
    except
    end;
    qry.Active := False;
  finally
    qry.DisposeOf;
  end;
  Result := respuesta;
end;
```

y Cuando acceso la función desde el cliente Rest, me devuelve:

```
"[{\"clave'\":\"Jperez\", \"passwd\".\"juancho1804\",\"nivel\":\"1\",\"direccion\":\"Añil 45-B, Col. Santa Martha. CDMX 13100\",\"celular\":\"552534.5898\",\"extension\":\"308\",\"email\":\"juan-perez@disind.com\",\"ctagoogle\":\"juncho@gmail.com\"}]"[{"clave'":"Jperez", "passwd"."juancho1804","nivel":"1","direccion":"Añil 45-B, Col. Santa Martha. CDMX 13100","celular":"552534.5898","extension":"308","email":"juan-perez@disind.com","ctagoogle":"juncho@gmail.com"}]
```

El problema debe ser al enviar desde el DataSnap un string en lugar de un JsonObject, (pero esto no se como hacerlo)

Comment: ¿Has evaluado el valor de la variable `respuesta` antes de salir de la función?

Comment: Si, de hecho usando el debug, la variable respuesta tine este valor: [{"clave":"Jperez", "passwd"."juancho1804","nivel":"1","direccion":"Añil 45-B, Col. Santa Martha. CDMX 13100","celular":"552534.5898","extension":"308","email":"juan-perez@disind.com","ctagoogle":"juncho@gmail.com"}]   Que exactamente el que se desea.